Function javascript for google sheets scraping web error
Tried to perform a javascript function for Google Sheets for webscaping in order to extract data from the site, in particular the share price of a company.
I have the following error:

Exception: Error on line 17: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
obtenerValorBarrickGold

function obtenerValorBarrickGold() {
  var url = "https://es.investing.com/equities/barrick-gold-corp.";
  var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  
  // Fetch the HTML content of the URL
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var html = response.getContentText();
  
  // Parse the HTML content
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);  
  var root = doc.getRootElement();

  // Extract the desired value using XPath
  var xpath = XmlService.getXPath();
  var elements = xpath.selectNodes(doc, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]");

  
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    var valor = elements[0].getText();
    return valor;
  } else {
    return "No se pudo encontrar el valor.";
  }
}




No, i can't get any of those to work, and I don't know if they are safe to use.
